# How to create JSON string in Sequel Pro TEXT editor?

Tags: mysql, json, actionscript-3, amfphp, sequelpro

I figure this may be an unconventional way of creating a JSON string. But, I really need to just be able to make it right in "Sequel Pro" like this

[image]

I want to be able to just edit it right there like that. But when I receive the string on the client end, then try to use as3 JSON.parse function on it, it gets an error...`"SyntaxError: Error #1132: Invalid JSON parse input."`

```
 private function storyTextCallBack(r:Object):void
            {

                        //storyText is an 'Object'
                storyText = JSON.parse(r.text);

            }
```

But this is how my client is actually getting it, and it's what I think is breaking the JSON.parse function.....

```
 [\n\t{\n\t\ttext: "hello this is some json test stuff",\n\t\tduration: "5000"\n\t},\n\t{\n\t\ttext: "this is the second line in that json object thing",\n\t\tduration: "3000"\n\t},\n\t{\n\t\ttext: "this is the third and final line in that json object thing",\n\t\tduration: "8000"\n\t}\n]
```

anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object names in your JSON need to be inside quotes:

```
"text":"example text"
```

You can check if you have a valid JSON object with this parser: http://json.parser.online.fr

Comment: wow, can't believe i overlooked that. I got distracted thinking it was adding extra characters and things. Great, easily fixed. Thanks again!